# How do I git -commit everything except what is in a subdirectory?

Tags: git

I'm building my app on Openshift.

But I need to find out how I can run

```
git commit -m "Some reason"
```

without affecting what is in a `/users/*` subdirectory. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you want to ignore this folder permanently? or only for one commit?

Comment: I want to permanently ignore it on future commits

Comment: you should add this folder to file `.gitignore`, then `git add .gitignore` and `git commit -m 'add users folder to gitignore'`

Comment: How do I edit gitignore? Also, if I just add say  /users  will it also ignore the subdirectories under it?

Comment: It's just text file, and subdirectories will be also ignored

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with these steps:

- add `users` folder to file .gitignore
- `git add .gitignore`
- `git commit -m 'add users folder to gitignore'`

After these steps folder `users` will be out of version control

Comment: just to make sure the syntax is correct. In .gitignore would I enter  users/*  or /users/* ?

Comment: right syntax is `/users`, with this string you will ignore `users` folder with any subfolders

Comment: What is the easiest way to open and edit the .gitignore file on my mac?

Comment: you can use any texteditor, I prefer ide like `idea`, `pycharm` and others, also you can use `sublime text editor`

Comment: I never did anything to .gitgnore, but when I typed vim .gitignore, it already has a bunch of stuff in there. Do I need to remove that suff, or just add /users ?

Comment: you just need to add one particular string `/users` and don't touch others

Comment: So, what is happening now is it doesn't add files, but it deletes new files that are added on the server version when I push... So that is not what I want. I don't want pushed to have any affect on what is in the \users directory on the server

Answer (score 0):

git commit only commits the files & directories which you have staged for commit.  So 'git add' only what you want to commit & you will be fine.  If you run 'git status' you can see a list of what is staged for commit.  Here's a good resource for more information on basic git flows: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: Thanks for the tips... But I find the reason/beauty of a tool like Stackoverflow is that, for quick questions, we don't have to resort to pulling out the manuals ;-)